# NameError: name 'attribute' is not defined

Tags: python

I have been trying to re-write the following code but it doesn't work, can anyone help to fix this?

The original code:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    for attributeNum, attribute in enumerate(self.attributes):
        if attributeNum == len(self.attributes) - 1:
            string += str(attribute)
        else:
            string += str(attribute) + ','
    return string
```

Re-written code:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    update_string = string+str(attribute)
    result = [update_string if attributeNum == len(self.attributes) - 1 else update_string + ','
              for attributeNum, attribute in enumerate(self.attributes)]
    print(result)
    return string
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "MyClassifier.py", line 218, in <module>
        classifier.test()
    File "MyClassifier.py", line 170, in test
        current_entry = (testEntry.euclidean(trainEntry), str(trainEntry.diabetes), str(trainEntry)
    File "MyClassifier.py", line 15, in __str__
        update_string = string+str(attribute)
NameError: name 'attribute' is not defined
```

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k).  Please don't post an image of the Traxceback (or code or data either).

Comment: The error says it all, there is no `attribute` variable defined in the second case

Comment: Then you need `self.attribute` instead of `attribute`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Why not just `return ",".join(attribute for attribute in self.attributes)`?

Answer (score 0):

The `attribute` variable is declared in your for loop, so it is not yet defined - hence why the error message says "name 'attribute' is not defined". May fixes are possible; here is one:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = ""
    update_string = string+str(attribute)
    result = [update_string if attributeNum == len(self.attributes) - 1 else update_string + ','
              for attributeNum, attribute in enumerate(self.attributes)]
    print(result)
    return string
```